# Why does the following base case for recursion in C not work?

Tags: c, recursion, return, function-definition

I am practicing recursion function in C. The question is to create a recursive function to print a sum of all of the elements (int) in an array without changing the main function.

I know how to write the base case with

```
int recursive(int a[], int size, int i) {
  if (i>=size){
    return 0; 
  }
  return a[i] + recursive(a, size, i+1); 
}
```

However, I was wondering why the base case for the following code does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int recursive(int a[], int size, int i) {
  if (i==size-1){
    return a[size-1]; 
  }
  return a[0] + recursive(a, size, i+1); 
}

int main(void) {

  int arrSize;

  printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");

  scanf("%d", &arrSize);

  int arr[arrSize];

  printf("Please enter the elements of the array: ");

  for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    
  int result = recursive(arr, arrSize, 0);

  printf("The result is %d.\n", result);

  return 0;

}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: For what inputs does your code not work?  What does it do that differs from your expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this return statement

```
return a[0] + recursive(a, size, i+1);
```

there is always used the array element `a[0]` instead of `a[i]`

Also even the first recursive function is unsafe due to the types of its parameneters and the presence of the third parameter.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
int recursive( const int a[], size_t size ) 
{
    return size == 0 ? 0 : a[0] + recursive( a + 1, size - 1 );
}
```

And the function is called like

```
int result = recursive(arr, arrSize);

printf("The result is %d.\n", result);
```

Though the return type of the function should be `long long int` to avoid overflow.

As you can see the third parameter is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think I am still confused on what you mean. If the size of the array is 1 would it not go straight to the first if statement and return a[0] instead of the second return? And thank you for the alternative solution and I understand how it works. However, the condition of the question was that the main function could not be altered so I cannot change the parameters and the argument for the third parameter is assigned as 0 in the main function.

Comment: I am wondering if I would be adding a[0] twice if I do the second base case? Since i is given as 0 in the main function and perhaps both the first and the second return statements add a[0] in return?

Comment: @tnwl.suzy I am sorry. I was in hurry and was not attentive. Of course there will be executed the first if statement. Pay attention to that it is a general function that should process any passed values even if the user will pass 0 for the parameter size. In this case your second function will invoke undefined behavior.